# ASP.net Web Site referencing code files with dependencies on non-compiled code

Tags: asp.net, compilation, webforms

I have a website that is not utilizing the App_Code folder for jit compiling code files (that is what App_code is for, right?).  Instead developers have to either cram all the necessary classes that they need for a page into the code file, or into an individual .cs file that gets and Assembly Directive src on the page (this is because of dependencies between the source files).

Is there any way for classes with dependencies on each other to be placed in separate files?

For instance Presenter.cs has a dependency on Model.cs.  I would like to just add an assembly directive to my page for Presenter.cs, and make it happy.  But since this does not compile Model.cs, it doesn't work.  Adding Assembly references for both code files also does not work.

Is there a mechanism that I am missing?

EDIT:  I think the answer is that the App_Code folder is exactly created for this task and that there is no other/better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "CodeBehind" are you actually referring to "CodeFile"? (One of the many reasons I'm not a fan of "ASP.NET Websites" and prefer MVC).

AFAIK, the ASP.NET runtime compiles all of the App_Code files together into their own assembly, however code in each page's CodeFile (not their CodeBehind) can only reference this anonymous assembly and not each others' code.

Can you clarify what you mean by "page assembly reference"? Are you doing `<%@ Assembly %>` or do you mean a namespace import `<%@ Import %>` (because as I said, a lot of the code is compiled into an anonymous assembly).

I suggest you just move the common code and classes to *.cs files within App_Code. It should just work.

Comment: As I said, the site is not utilizing the App_code folder.  When I say Assembly reference on the page, I mean the Assembly Directive.  And yes, I did mean CodeFile, not code behind.